# Python 3 Subprocess.stdin.write does not work | omxplayer class

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess, stdin, omxplayer

For one of my projects, I need a way to create a custom Media Player class. to fo that I create a simple class that calls omxplayer with the given url and writes to the stdin letters like 'p' to pause, 'q' to quit... and so on
Here is my code

```
import subprocess
import time

class MediaPlayer():
        def __init__(self):
                self.url = None
                self.process = None
        def play(self, url):
                self.url = url
                self.process = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local', self.url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        def stop(self):
                self.process.stdin.write('q'.encode())
        def toogle_pause(self):
                self.process.stdin.write(b'p')

url = "/home/pi/Desktop/IOS MIRROR/films/Game.of.Thrones.S01E02.HDTV.VF.avi"

print('start')
media_player = MediaPlayer()
media_player.play(url)
time.sleep(15)
print('pause')
media_player.toogle_pause()
time.sleep(2)
print('resume')
media_player.toogle_pause()
time.sleep(10)
print('stop')
media_player.stop()
```

This works perfectly fine on python2.7, when I execute the command

```
python omx.py
```

but as soon as i execute the command

```
python3 omx.py
```

None of my write lines works, The video plays but it doesn't pause and stop. there is no error printed so I am really stucked.
For informations, I am on a Raspberry Pi 3 powered by Raspbian.
I need it to work on python3 because my Mirror project is using Python3

[image]

Thanks everyone for your answers!
Best regards, Julien

Comment: Possibly the data you are writing to the external program is being line-buffered.  Try `self.process.stdin.flush()` after each write.

Comment: Oh yes! it works very fine now ! Thank you really much, after adding the flush() method, everythng works !

Answer (score 0):

Resurrecting this because I just came across this and I'm not convinced the comment from jasonharper gives the full answer.

The reason is that the default for `bufSize` in `Popen` has changed from 0 (unbuffered) in python2 to 1 (line-buffered) in python3. Calling `stdin.flush()` after each write is one solution, but probably nicer is just to set this explicitly when creating the `Popen` by setting `bufSize=0`.

That should then result in the script working consistently in both python2 and 3.